# Bootstrap 3 responsive dropdown hover menu doesn't work on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to create a responsive menu with dropdown submenu items on it. So far it is working on desktop, but it doesn't work on mobile (i am testing on an iPhone 5s).

Here are my code:

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top" style="padding-top: 0px !important">

      </a>
    </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Submenu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Submenu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Submenu3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**I tried to solve the problem on 2 ways:**

**1.** I tried to add jquery (but then i realized I am not good enough to write a good code alone) - I also read that I should have used "listenWidth()" but I really don't know how to.

```
function dropdown() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 780) {
    jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
      jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeIn();
    }, function() {
      jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(50).fadeOut();
    });
}
}

// Execute on load
dropdown();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(dropdown);
```

**2.** I tried to do it with hidden-xs, visible-xs, but it did not work as well.

Please help me!

Thanks, 
F

Comment: Try to resize your desktop browser to mobile screen size and test menu drop-down. Is it works?

Comment: I just don't get it, the hoverable dropdown menus on touch devices (especially on mobile device). Since touch is their only pointer, I don't think the hover function is really necessary. BTW your code is actually working on my Xperia mini I'm using right now. Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/xijanifoya/edit?output) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks alright. Check if you have added jQuery library before bootsrtap JS.

I added the following and your code works when I resize the browser to xs width:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

http://codepen.io/pavithraolety/pen/vKbGXL/

Your jquery snippet is not required.

Answer (score 0):

To open dropdown bootstrap adds class "open" to

```
<li class="dropdown">
```

So, to open it properly you should add/remove it.

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').hover(function(e) {
   $('li.dropdown').toggleClass('open');
})
```

The next step is to apply class togglign to parent only.

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').hover(function(e) {
  $(e.currentTarget).parent().toggleClass('open');
})
```

Next this handler should not be executed on touchscreen...bare in mind that mobile device could be connected with TV + Mouse. That is difficult to check and handle, but if you do not care about it, just return from this event as you did

```
$(window).width() < 780
```

Hope that helps